# how can i stop custom fields that have apostrophes from breaking my code

Tags: custom-field

I have this code in my php file that creates a button labeled from a field called speaker_file_label and links to a pdf file based on the url entered in the speker_file_url.  The fields are created by ACF

```
    echo do_shortcode(  "[av_button label='".get_sub_field('speaker_file_label')."' link='manually,".get_sub_field ('speaker_file_url')."' link_target='_blank' size='medium' position='left' color='theme-color']" ).'<br>';
```

This works perfectly when someone just enters text.  However if they say somehting like "joe's files" (without quotes)  Then the shortcode breaks and the label just becomes "click"

How can i make wordpress not interpret that apostrophe as part of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could apply the content filters:

```
    echo do_shortcode(  "[av_button label='".apply_filters('the_content',(get_sub_field('speaker_file_label'))."' link='manually,".get_sub_field ('speaker_file_url')."' link_target='_blank' size='medium' position='left' color='theme-color']" ).'<br>';
```

the above added pp marks `<p></p>`

try this:

```
    echo do_shortcode(  "[av_button label='".wptexturize( get_sub_field('speaker_file_label'))."' link='manually,".get_sub_field ('speaker_file_url')."' link_target='_blank' size='medium' position='left' color='theme-color']" ).'<br>';
```

Comment: this brought the text back but added paragraphs into my text, can i stop that portion with the filter?

Comment: made changes...use wptexturize

Comment: If he uses the `the_content` filter hook, the content of the field will go through all functions hooked to it, weird things will follow.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap user input in [esc_html()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html).

Using your example:

```
    echo do_shortcode( "[av_button 
        label='" . esc_html( get_sub_field( 'speaker_file_label' ) ) . "' 
        link='manually," . esc_html( get_sub_field ( 'speaker_file_url' ) )."' 
        link_target='_blank'
        size='medium' position='left' color='theme-color']" ).'<br>';
```

You can make it more readable:

```
$shortcode = sprintf( "[av_button label='%1$s' link='manually,%2$s' link_target='_blank' size='medium' position='left' color='theme-color']"
    , esc_html( get_sub_field( 'speaker_file_label' ) )
    , esc_html( get_sub_field( 'speaker_file_url' ) )
);

echo do_shortcode( $shortcode ) . '<br>';
```

Comment: There are multiple benefits to this approach.  esc_html is very powerful

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix it, would be to invert your quotes from the outset (replace all double quotes (") with single quotes (') and vice versa.

```
echo do_shortcode(  '[av_button label="' . get_sub_field('speaker_file_label') . '" link="manually,' . get_sub_field ('speaker_file_url') . '" link_target="_blank" size="medium" position="left" color="theme-color"]' ).'<br>';
```

But that won't stop if people use double quotes ("), so you can escape them, by using [addslashes](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp)

```
echo do_shortcode(  '[av_button label="' . addslashes( get_sub_field('speaker_file_label') ) . '" link="manually,' . addslashes( get_sub_field ('speaker_file_url') ) . '" link_target="_blank" size="medium" position="left" color="theme-color"]' ) . '<br>';
```

This should fix most issues, the first one might fix them all if you don't expect people to use double quotes.  I haven't tested either, so let me know if they worked for you or not.

Comment: this didn't work.  The first option you're correct, someone might use quotes.  The 2nd option didn't make any changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can write "`&#39;`" instead of `'` (single quotation mark) in your text fields.

Comment: The question is about processing user input though. You can't ask your users to do that, nor can you rely on them, nor should you.